# Is burnt microwave safe to use?

Tags: microwave, burnt

[image: this is tbe inside of my microwave]Microwave popcorn left a burnt hole on the little metal plate inside the microwave. It still, works perfectly fine.  But is it safe food wise? Should i use it?

Comment: This sounds like it may be more of an electronics question than a cooking question... Generally speaking, electronics with burn damage should be considered potentially unsafe, as they may be a fire hazard.

Comment: Are you sure that's burned metal? Metal doesn't burn... My microwave has a cardboardish piece covering some hole like that. I think it's called a wave guide cover. You can order a new one (e.g., online) and just replace it. The black stains could just be from the burning cardboard. Try wiping them off.

Answer (score 2):

That's not a metal plate. it's heat resistant mica composite. The microwaves come into the oven through the hole behind it. You can take it out scrub it off, put it back in and be good to to go. Be gentle with the stuff. It'll crack if you scrub too hard. From the soot marks on the metal above the piece, you must have had a big blob of grease explode onto the shield, where it burned merrily. Clean the soot off too.
Pull the piece up gently to remove, and push it down under the clips to put it back.

Comment: The OP says there's an actual hole in it, in which case I'd suggest it's not safe to use. If it's just a mark your advice would be correct.

Comment: I don't see it. If there is an actual hole through it, you can buy a replacement, cheap: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=microwave+mica+waveguide+cover&t=ffsb&ia=products

Answer (score -2):

I have always been told by my dad that a fire in ANY electric appliance warrants an expert who is knowledgeable in the repair of the appliance before it is used again. Electricity is one thing, microwaves are another. All of the shields are there to protect you and your family. What price will you pay later to save a few dollars. My advice is take it outside and destroy it. People go thru dumpsters to pick up stuff and sell it to someone who is trying to save money. If it works use it is bad advice. But do what you want and I hope you sleep well